# large double gets rounded off to int - C++

Tags: c++

I ran the following code on http://cpp.sh/

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double avg = 112964.6;
    cout << avg << endl;
}
```

I get 112965 as the output. I have tried it in other compilers - same result.

It works for smaller double values like 11296.6 but a large double like 112964.6 gets rounded off to int. Why is it doing that and how do I stop it from doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "It works for smaller double values"? What values are you expecting?

Comment: for avg = 11296.6, I get 11296.6 in the output - no rounding off

Comment: Have you tried `setprecision()`?  Its default value is 6, which is why it's rounding as you have described.

Comment: use this .....cout << setprecision(11) << avg << endl;  add the namespace #include <iomanip>

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about '<iomanip>' and 'setprecision()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set what's the decimal precision to be used, you can do it with stream manipulator `setprecision (int n)` where `n` will be the new precision to be used.

You can look at the following example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/:

```
// setprecision example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision



int main () {
     double f =3.14159;
     std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
     std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
     std::cout << std::fixed;
     std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
     std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
     return 0;
   }
```

Where the expected output should be:

```
3.1416
3.14159
3.14159
3.141590000
```

Answer (score 2):

try [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double avg = 112964.6;
    cout << setprecision(9) << avg << endl;
}
```